# Building python Shell

Tags: python, shell

I have some small python 2.6 scripts built....

Now, I would like run them as seperate processes within a python shell. Each as a seperate process. If one fails to run maybe with its timer, I would like others to continue without killing all scripts.

Should I do this as singleton gui's or combine them into bigger launch pad. My perference would be launch pad type gui....Any ideas?

Its seems that launching scripts out of SciTE, works ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [joblaunch](http://code.google.com/p/joblaunch/), a shell tool I made for executing interdependent jobs in parallel locally. It has more options.